# implementing jQuery.contains() in jqLite (AngularJS)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I'm writing a library in which I need to check if an element is detached from the DOM before doing operations on it, because it is possible that the element is removed from outside the library. This would be possible as follows: `jQuery.contains(document, myJqLiteElement)`. However, jqLite does not include such a function. In order to remove jQuery as an dependency for my library, I need to figure out an alternative. One way to solve it, is by implementing some API point at which a user can signal to this library that an element was removed. This is not a very elegant method, however.

What is an alternative implementation for jQuery.contains() in jqLite (AngularJS)?

Comment: You do know that you can see the source code of jQuery, right? So first [read it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/selector-native.js#L197) and then try to implement it.

Comment: *This is not a very elegant method, however* - but a very wise one. Why should a costly check be performed each time, just because a user was too lazy to perform one action? Any way, it's up to you and depends on what's it all about